# |"Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-1.8. There are no JREs installed in workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment."

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Eclipse:
Version: 2022-03 (4.23.0)
Build id: 20220310-1457

JDK installed: JDK-18.0.1.1 (from https://openjdk.java.net/)

have been trying to solve the problem playing with:

[image: Java Build Path :]

[image: Java Compiler:]

[image: Project Facets:]

Have also Maven Dependency in pom.xml:

```
 <build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Stuck for a week with that:)

Comment: Expand that JRE System Library node. What is your project actually pointing to?

Comment: Have you told Eclipse about the Java 8 in the Preferences in "Java > Installed JREs"?

Comment: Don't have access now to Eclipse IDE where I got stuck the problem But have the same problem under Fedora Linux Eclipse. The message is: "The compiler compliance specified is 1.8 but a JRE 17 is used"  Ok.                                                                          Preferences->Java->Installed JREs indicates /opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.linux.x86_64_17.0.2.v20220201-1208/jre. (i.e. installed within eclipse). I did change all the entries pointing to this JRE and JDK (17) It works. Many thanks!) Try to do the same under Windows Eclipse in few days

Comment: But with that done there is a new problem: with maven-compiler-plugin. Because there was entries <source> and <target> with the value 1.8. I tried to remove <configuration> from there. Now some settings (JRE Libraries and JDK in Project Facets) are reset to 1.6 (in Build Path) or to 1.7 if I set maven-compiler-plugin <version> to be 3.10.1.   haven't got a clue how to fill <configuration> section for maven-compliler-plugin to use Java 17 with it. If I remove maven-compliler-plugin from pom.xml and update project this leads again to reset JRE Library in Build Path and Project Facets to Java 1.7

Comment: Have the same error in vscode